# Swapping strings between nodes in C

Tags: c, string, linked-list, nodes, swap

I'm trying to swap the data fields between nodes in my linked list, having trouble swapping the char arrays. this is just a sample of the program.

```
struct node {
    int count;
    char word[50];
    struct node *next;
};

void swap_nodes( struct node *first, struct node *second ) {
    int temp_count;
    char *temp_word;

    temp_count = first->count;
    temp_word = first->word;
    first->count = second->count;
    first->word = second->word;
    second->count = temp_count;
    second->word = temp_word;
}
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong, I'm very new at writing in c.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some indication of what behavior you are seeing that you were not expecting, or which behavior you were expecting that you are not seeing?

Comment: `char word[50]` is array, it can not be assigned, you need to copy char arrays by `strcpy` or `memcpy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign an array of characters to a pointer, you do not make a copy of the array:

```
char *temp_word;
temp_word = first->word;
```

`temp_word` points to the initial element of the array, so assigning to the array would change the data pointed to by the pointer as well.

You can fix this by declaring an array of 50 characters, and using `strcpy` or `memcpy` to do the copying:

```
char temp_word[50];
memcpy(temp_word, first->word, sizeof(temp_word));
memcpy(first->word, second->word, sizeof(temp_word));
memcpy(second->word, temp_word, sizeof(temp_word));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have already received answers, I just want to point out that you could exchange the nodes position in the list (instead the node content). As you have a single linked list, you will need the parents of the nodes to do so.

Alternatively, you can use dynamic memory instead the static array for "word", this way you only have to swap the pointers, avoiding the array copy.

Answer (score 0):

The `word[50]` is a part of `struct node`, it's inside of the `struct node`, while what you have done is just move a pointer `*temp_word` point to `*first`, then to `*second`, the content of the `word[50]` is not changed in deeply. you can use `memcpy` to change the contents.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate implementation with `strncpy` and `strdup` would be:

```
#include <string.h>

void swap_nodes( struct node *first, struct node *second ) {
    int temp_count;
    char *temp_word;

    temp_count = first->count;
    temp_word = strdup (first->word);
    first->count = second->count;
    strncpy (first->word, second->word, 50);    /* 50 based on struct definition       */
    second->count = temp_count;                 /* could be ( strlen (temp_word) + 1 ) */
    strncpy (second->word, temp_word, 50);

    if (temp_word)                              /* free memory allocated with strdup   */
        free (temp_word);
}
```